# ¿por que dentro de este iterable no se tiene acceso al atributo de la clase en python?

Tags: python

Cuando me encontraba desarrollando un programa en Python 3, en una de mis clases opte por usar
una lista por comprensión como atributo de la clase y un entero como otro atributo de la misma clase, usando dicha variable del entero dentro del iterable. Así como esto:

```
class A:
    a = 7
    b = [[0 for j in range(a)] for i in range(3)]

    def mostrar(self):
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)

ins = A()
ins.mostrar()
```

Cuando lo compile me genero esto sobre la linea 3:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Despues reemplace el valor de `b` con esto:

```
b=[0 for i in range(a)]
```

Lo compile y no me genero un error:

```
7
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Reemplace una vez mas el valor de `b`:

```
b=[0 for i in range(3) if a==7]
```

y lo compile:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Al final deduje que después del nivel del for-in dentro del iterable respecto al orden de evaluación ya no reconoce ningún atributo de clase.
¿Alguien sabe por que sucede esto?

Comment: más que nada, se debe a tu *list comprehension*

Comment: Uh, ¡buenísima pregunta! La respuesta es muy compleja y me dejó pensando (e investigando) un rato. Afortunadamente, en el sitio en inglés está [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition) dada por el gran Martijn Pieters.

Comment: @revliscano justo estaba escribiendo una respuesta :/

Comment: @Christian ¡Wow! ¡Mis respetos profundos para ti si sabías la respuesta a eso! Si la sabes y la estabas escribiendo, compártela. Igual es bueno que quede acá en el sitio en español.

Comment: @revliscano sip, aunque leyendo lo que mandas no sabía que esto era propio de python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Y aquí otra victima más del *scope*.

Bueno, para empezar, sabemos que al declarar una clase podemos estableces métodos y atributos, para los atributos podemos designar que sean de solo lectura o de solo escritura (o ambos), estos atributos puedes ser creados ya dentro de la clase o ser creados fuera de la clase con `clase.atributo = "hola"`.

En Python existen los *Namespace* o *espacios de nombres*, esto es una relación que hay entre un nombre y un objeto, entre estos encontramos los nombre globales en un módulo, los nombre locales, etc. Esto esta muy relacionado con el *scope* de una variable, pues 2 variables con espacios de nombres distintos no tienen ninguna relación. Si tu tienes una variable `saludo = "hola"` declarada en tú código y luego tienes una función asi:

```py
saludo = "hola"

def saludar():
    saludo+= " :)"
    print(saludo)

saludar()
```

Esto dará un bonito error :), pues la variable saludo que está dentro de la función no es igual (no hace referencia) a la que está fuera de la función.

La propia documentación de Python nos dice que cada *namespace* se crea de forma distinta, en diferentes momentos y con distintos tiempos de vida.

> Namespaces are created at different moments and have different lifetimes. The namespace containing the built-in names is created when the Python interpreter starts up, and is never deleted.

Pero como que aquí hay algo que no cuadra, pues también se dice que estas variables no son borradas, por lo que aun *queda existencia* de ellas, entonces por que se dice que la variable `a` no ha sido referenciada o no se tiene referencia de esta?, pues como dije en mi comentario:

> más que nada, se debe a tu *list comprehension*

Y es que las comprensiones de lista implementan algunos *trucos* (copiados de los generadores), para hacer un trabajo rápido se les asigna un marco de trabajo independiente y nuevo por lo que usan las variables que están a su alcance (scope) y como se ha creado un nuevo marco de trabajo para la comprensión de lista, la variable `a` no esta dentro de su alcance por lo que *no ha sido referenciada*.

Esto explica por que si declaramos la variable como `global` si funciona.

```py
class A:
    global a
    a = 7
    b = [[0 for j in range(a)] for i in range(3)]

ins = A()
print(ins.b)
```

**resultado**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Al declarar la variable como `global` su *namespace* se *extiende* haciendo que esta variable sea accesible por cualquier marco de trabajo creado. La documentación lo deja más claro:

> Si un nombre se declara como global, entonces todas las referencias y asignaciones al mismo van directo al ámbito intermedio que contiene los nombres globales del módulo. [...] La declaración global puede usarse para indicar que ciertas variables viven en el ámbito global y deberían reasignarse allí

Y ahora surge la pregunta de ¿por qué funciona con la comprensión de lista *normal*? (segundo ejemplo). Esto se debe a que, como menciona revliscano en su comentario, existen *excepciones*, donde en una comprensión de lista anidada, solo el iterable más exterior (o el ultimo) se ejecuta en el ámbito local y esto explica el por qué tu comprensión de lista (de un solo iterable) funciona, también lo puedes hacer en la comprensión de lista anidada pero utilizando la variable `a` en el ultimo `for`

```py
class A:
    # global a
    a = 7
    b = [[0 for j in range(3)] for i in range(a)]

clase = A()
print(clase.b)
```

**resultado**

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

También tendrás otro problema al usar tu método `mostrar()`, al hacer `print(self.a)` estas haciendo referencia a las variables de una instancia y tu no has declarado un constructor (o inicializador) `def __init__(self)`, y de todas formas, si quitas el `self` tendras otro error por el *scope* :)

Como complemento te dejo estos links que te pueden servir (están en ingles)

- [Accessing class variables from a list comprehension in the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition)
- [List comprehension rebinds names even after scope of comprehension. Is this right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/list-comprehension-rebinds-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-this-righ)

Comment: Pues en líneas generales, un buena respuesta (+1). Pero yendo al punto, es porque: 1. Las comprehensiones poseen su propio scope. 2. Los nombres definidos en los bloques de las clases solo están disponibles dentro de ese bloque y **no** se extienden a bloques internos de códigos (como las comprehensiones) ni métodos.

Comment: Y es importante hacer la salvedad que existe una excepción: Los nombres definidos en los bloques de las clases estarán disponibles en el iterable más exterior de las comprehensiones definidas en dichos bloques. Por esa razón funciona el segundo ejemplo (`b=[0 for i in range(a)]`) dado por OP.

Comment: Cierto, me había olvidado de especificar eso y explicar por qué si le funciona en el segundo ejemplo

Comment: @revliscano ya lo he añadido :D

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, recién me entere que el ámbito de las clases no llegaban a todo el iterable por comprensión como atributo de esta clase. No declare un inicializador por que no vi que era necesario, solo lo uso cuando simplemente quiero inicializar valores del objeto.